# How to get onyl part of the URL in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am creating a module using C# which will need to refer the URL
So i have 2 example URLs for you here.

http://www.website.com/ProductDetail/tabid/86/rvdsfpid/1gb-dual-port-iscsi-8660/rvdsfmfid/qlogic-174/Default.aspx

&&

http://www.website.com/ProductDetail/tabid/86/rvdsfpid/49950/default.aspx

Now what i need from both the URls is the product ID which in the first case is 8660 & the second case is 49950. I cannot change the way these URls are generated. The easiest way would have been

http://www.website.com/ProductDetail/tabid/86/default.aspx?rvdsfpid=49950
and then i could do the following and life would be easy.

```
string Pid= Request.Querystring["rvdsfpid"];
```

However since i dont have control on the way the URL is generatyed how can i catch the URL and fetch only the productId.

Comment: Given a URL like the first example, how do you figure out which part is the Product ID?

Comment: The relative position of the searched URL is the same in both examples: it is in the block that starts behind "www.website.com/ProductDetail/tabid/86/rvdsfpid/" and ends with the next "/" so getting that part as a string is no problem, but that in 1 example there is just the ID you are looking for in this block and in the second example there is the ID you are looking for AND data we do not care about, so how do you know what data you care about ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's the URL format you're being passed and there's nothing else you can do....You're going to need to get the full url and then split it. Here's the basic, you're going to have to add some extra checks and stuff in there;

```
string url = "http://www.website.com/ProductDetail/tabid/86/rvdsfpid/1gb-dual-port-iscsi-8660/rvdsfmfid/qlogic-174/Default.aspx"
//string url = "http://www.website.com/ProductDetail/tabid/86/rvdsfpid/49950/default.aspx";

url = url.Replace("http://", ""); //get rid of that, add code to check for https?
string[] x = url.Split('/');
string productCode = x[5]; //assuming the product code is always the 6th item in the array!

string code = "";
if (productCode.IndexOf("-") > -1)
{
    code = productCode.Substring(productCode.LastIndexOf("-")+1);
}
else
{
    code = productCode;
}
```